# ".long ." What does it mean in arm assembly coding?

Tags: instruction-set

I was going through arch/arm/head.S and found below code

__turn_mmu_on_loc:

```
    .long   .
    .long   __turn_mmu_on
    .long   __turn_mmu_on_end
```

I am not able to understand ".long ."?

Answer (score 1):

See [GNU Assembler Manual: The Special Dot Symbol](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Int.html#Int):

> The special symbol '`.`' refers to the current address that **`as`** is
>   assembling into. Thus, the expression `melvin: .long .` defines `melvin`
>   to contain its own address. Assigning a value to `.` is treated the same
>   as a `.org` directive. Thus, the expression `.=.+4` is the same as
>   saying `.space 4`.

So in your snippet, the current address is placed before the value of the `__turn_mmu_on`, `__turn_mmu_on_end` symbols. You see constructs like these a lot in assembler files and linker scripts as they lay out their data structures.